# Capture client screen shot

Tags: javascript, typescript, screenshot

I am trying to capture client screen shot, and have some reference from https://github.com/html-screen-capture-js/html-screen-capture-js, but this gives me entire html page, I only want the contents of the `<body>`, can some-one please help me extract this.

I am not too comfortable with type-script and thus am not able to debug the code.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of window.document, capture only the specific element. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you need this (since all the style classes are added to the head), but anyway... When you call the capture method, by default, it returns an HTML document object. You can then simply pluck the body element from it by JavaScript.